# Insert into database and check if row already exist

Tags: php, mysql

I have simple input and I need help with MySQL.

When you click the submit button, PHP will need to check if the row already exist and only insert a new one if not.

I know the `INSERT` part, but don't know how to check if the row already exists.

Comment: mysql also provide a `REPLACE` for this kind of insert

Answer (score 2):

Either use `INSERT IGNORE` to do nothing if it already exists, or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to update fields on attempted insert.

**EDIT**

If you want to check to see if it exists, run a SELECT first, either as `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ...` and count the rows, or `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE ...` and check if the count is greater than 0 . If it exists, send a message to the user. If it does not, then go ahead and insert.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='".$email."'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count==0)  {
$sql="INSERT INTO user (email)VALUES('".$email."')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
header('Location:login.php');
}
else
{ 
echo 'already exist';
}
```

try this one

Answer (score -2):

No need for checking whether entry is already or nor just go to phpmyadmin and that particular table ,set unique to that entry and thats set.